# Using flip inside each not working in KDB

Tags: kdb

Using `each` on a table, I was expecting `each` to operate on one row at a time in the form of a one-row table. However, it is being converted to a dictionary first:

```
q) t:flip `a`b!(enlist 1;enlist 2);
q) {type x} each t
enlist 99h  / dictionary
```

So the obvious thing to do is just use `flip` to make the dictionary into a table:

```
q) {type flip x} each t
An error occurred during execution of the query.
The server sent the response:
rank
Studio Hint: Possibly this error refers to invalid rank or valence
```

Hmm - that's wierd. Can't `flip` a dictionary?? What's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that table is a list of dictionary.

```
q)show each ([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6);
a| 1
b| 4
a| 2
b| 5
a| 3
b| 6
```

http://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/

The values of each dictionary are atoms, not lists. So you can't `flip` a dictionary into a table that way, you have to make sure the values are lists.

```
q)enlist each ([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6)
+`a`b!(,1;,4)
+`a`b!(,2;,5)
+`a`b!(,3;,6)
q)type each enlist each ([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6)
98 98 98h
```

Comment: could be rewritten as `(type enlist@)each([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6)` (or even `('[type;enlist])each([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6)` if you want to get fancy)